# Write the implementation to pass this test

Tags: c#, programming-puzzle

Given the following test, implement an `addOne` function in C# so it passes, without any modification to the test. TIP: Yes, it is possible.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TheChallenge()
{
    int a = 1;

    addOne(a);

    Assert.IsTrue(a == 2);
}
```

**EDIT:** clarified the Assert to avoid confusion. The value of `a` should be 2; there's no trick there.

Comment: do you mean `void addOne(ref int a){a++;}`

Comment: That wouldn't compile. The ref keyword is not in the test (you would need `addOne(ref a);`).

Comment: Perhaps you could use reflection to somehow rewrite the IL for the test method to increment a after the return. That's all I can think of.

Comment: This isn't a very code golf friendly question.

Comment: @istepaniuk oh, I've never actually written any C#, so I googled and tried to understand the syntax for pass by reference.
MrZander: it isn't tagged code golf. It's awfully simple for puzzle though.

Comment: No need to rewrite IL on runtime. But it goes on those lines of nasty hack. TIP: unsafe code is allowed

Comment: @MrZander, @shiona; please tag accordingly, I'm new here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ummm, simply provide an implementation of AssertTrue that doesn't throw anything?

```
void addOne(int a){}

void AssertTrue(bool b) { }
```

You never specified what testing framework is used here. It looks like MSTest, but I fired up a new test project and AssertTrue doesn't exist, so I took the liberty of implementing it myself.

## EDIT

This solution might be what you were fishing for:

```
void addOne(int x)
{
  unsafe
  {
    int* i = &x;
    i += 4;
    *i += 1;
  }
}
```

I feels pretty fragile, but it works on my box consistently. It probably depends heavily on the compiler, so hopefully it is reproducible elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for lateral thinking, but the question states "Implement an addOne function" I will clarify the Assert to make it pure mstest.